# Where does the constant increase by 2 of differences between integer square values come from?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, intuition

$1^2 = 1$,
$2^2 = 4$,
$3^2 = 9$,
$4^2 = 16$,
$5^2 = 25$, etc...

Looking at the difference between those square values, we get: 3, 5, 7, 9, etc...

The difference from one (integer) square to the next increases by 2 without fault (let's assume).

Why is that? Why is there that pattern of increases by 2? What is it due to? What is the source of it?

I can "see" squaring visually as the construction of an actual square and I have drawn subdivided squares within squares to see the pattern unfold, but I just don't understand how to explain that increase by 2; I can't ***trace*** it, essentially.

Comment: Hint. Can you calculate $(x+1)^2) - x^2$?

Comment: $(n+1)^2-n^2=2n+1$

Comment: It's very much of the same origin as the second derivative of $f(x)=x^2$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, sorry I don't see it, do you mind explaining the connection?

Comment: Not him, but a derivative is infinitesimal difference whereas what you are looking at finite differences.

Comment: @DavidEtler, yes but I'm not sure where he's getting the "same origin" part from. I can see that the slope at each successive integer value of x is double that of the previous one, but I'm not sure I understand the connection in this context.

Comment: @jeremyradcliff We can show for $f(x) = x^2$, $D f(x) = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{(x+h)^2 - x^2}{h} = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{x^2 + 2xh + h^2 - x^2}{h} = 2x$ and $D^2f(x) = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{2(x+h) - (2x)}{h}= \color{red}{\lim_{h\to0} \frac{2h}{h} = 2}$. The key importance is in the second derivative: though it is a limit of values for $h$, the expression inside the limit is a constant. A finite difference ($a_{n+1} - a_n$) is essentially a difference quotient with $h=1$. Here, the expression is $2$ regardless of $h$.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

For a visual intuition.... The inner blue region increments the gray square by one, but to make the next increment you need the extra yellow unit squares to get to the following square.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the kind of intuition I was looking for.

Comment: @jeremyradcliff There are many related illustrations on the web, see e.g. [http://www.math.upenn.edu/~deturck/probsolv/LP1ans.html](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~deturck/probsolv/LP1ans.html).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, that's a great one too, thank you.

Comment: ... and if the increment is $k$ (instead of $1$), the second increment in squares is $2k^2$ bigger than the first.

Comment: IMHO even more intuition comes from shifting the yellow squares to the top right.

Answer (score 17):

We have the series
$$
x_n = n^2
$$
and the differences
$$
\Delta x_n = x_{n+1} - x_n = (n+1)^2 - n^2 = n^2 + 2n + 1 - n^2 = 2n + 1
$$
and the difference of differences
$$
\Delta x_{n+1} - \Delta x_n = (2(n+1)+1) - (2n+1) = 2n + 3 - 2n - 1 = 2
$$

Answer (score 9):

The difference between two adjacent squares, $(a+1)^2$ and $a^2$:

$$\begin{align}
(a+1)^2 - a^2 &= a^2 + 2a + 1 - a^2 \\
&= 2a + 1
\end{align}$$

So for each increase in $a$ by $1$, the delta between squares gets $2$ bigger.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $(a+1)^2-a^2=a^2+2a+1-a^2=2a+1$

Answer (score 2):

Let $a$ be some natural number, and then let's think about $a+1$.
Since $a^2 = a \cdot a$, we have $(a+1)^2 = a^2 + 2a + 1$.

Then $(a+1)^2 - a^2 = 2a + 1$.

And then note for the numbers $1,2,3,\ldots$ applying $2a+1$ gives $2\cdot 1 + 1, 2 \cdot 2 + 1, 3 \cdot 2 + 1,\ldots$ Which is:
$$3,5,7,9,\ldots$$