# $1^2$+$2^2$-$2×3^2$+$4^2$+$5^2$-$2×6^2$+$...$+$9997^2$+$9998^2$-$2×9999^2$

Tags: summation

∵ For any positive integer $n$

$n^2-2(n+1)^2+(n+2)^2$

= $n^2-2n^2-4n-2+n^2+4n+4=2$

∵ $1^2$+$2^2$-$2×3^2$+$4^2$+$5^2$-$2×6^2$+$...$+$9997^2$+$9998^2$-$2×9999^2$

= $1^2+(2^2-2×3^2+4^2)+(5^2-2×6^2+7^2)+...+(9995^2-2×9996^2+9997^2)+9998^2-2×9999^2$

= $1+(2+2+...+2)+9998^2-2×9999^2$

I do not know how many lots of two will be inside the aforementioned parenthesis.

Comment: come on seriously? you've done the hard work. there are 9999 terms but subtract the three you didn't include and divide that result by 3. That's (9999-3)/3 = 3332 2s.

Comment: factorise the difference of squares to do the rest

Comment: @gebra I realised after I spent time thinking. I had a mind blank. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There would be $((9995-2)/3)+1$ lots of 2.

Following;

$1+2×(((9995-2)/3)+1)+9998^2-2×9999^2$

$2×3332+(9998^2-9999^2)+(1-9999^2)$

$6664+(9998-9999)(9998+9999)+(1-9999)(1+9999)$

$6664-19997-99980000$

= $-99993333$

Answer (score 1):

Filling a gap for the benefit of other readers:

$$\begin{align}
(n-1)^2 -2n^2 + (n+1)^2 &= (n^2-2n+1) -2n^2+(n^2+2n+1) \\
&=2n^2-2n^2+2n-2n+2 \\
&=2
\end{align}$$

or:

$$\begin{align}
(n-1)^2 -2n^2 + (n+1)^2 &= ((n+1)^2-n^2) - (n^2-(n-1)^2)  \\
&=(n+1+n)(n+1-n) - (n+n-1)(n-(n-1)) \\
&=(2n+1) - (2n-1) \\
&=2
\end{align}$$

or simply "[the difference between squares increases by two each time](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1271618/where-does-the-constant-increase-by-2-of-differences-between-integer-square-valu)"

And the accumulated number of $2$s from this will be one-third the number of terms involved in these equations, $9996/3$.

---

Revisiting this, we could use another grouping. The alternative pattern repeat of interest is:

$\begin{align}(n-2)^2+(n-1)^2-2n^2 &= n^2-4n+4 +n^2-2n+1 -2n^2 \\
&=-6n+5
\end{align}$

And the $n$ values here have the form $3k$, giving the full sum as

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{3333}(5-6(3i)) &= 3333\cdot5-18 \frac{3333\cdot 3334}{2} \\
&=3333(5-30006) = 3333\times -30001  \\
&=-99993333
\end{align}$$