# simplify a numerical expression without calculator

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, primitive-roots

The following term:
$$\sqrt{2017^2-2018^2+2019^2}$$
is the same as this term:
$$\sqrt{2018^2+2}$$
how can one show without the need of a calculator that these are the same?

The original question was the following:
How long is the distance between point A and D - the diagonals are orthogonal and the other distances as labeled [image]

I then called the point where the diagonals meet $M$ and with the help of the Pythagoras' theorem I came up with the following equations:

$$ AM^2 + BM^2 = 2017^2  $$
$$ AM^2 + CM^2 = 2018^2  $$
$$ CM^2 + DM^2 = 2019^2  $$
$$ DM^2 + AM^2 = AD^2  $$

By rearrange the first three equations I had the following term:

$$AD^2 = 2017^2-2018^2+2019^2 $$
as the solution given was:
$$ AD = \sqrt{2018^2+2}$$
I was curious how to tell it was the same

Are there any other "nicer" ways to find this solution?

Comment: How were you planning to do it with a calculator?

Comment: What are these square roots doing here?

Comment: the root comes from the actual problem - but it's not important

Comment: @oneguy `the root comes from the actual problem - but it's not important` It's still important in the sense that the `actual problem` might well have a simpler or more direct solution without going through those square roots. See [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: oh, I'm sorry - I'll change it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$2017^2=(2018-1)^2=2018^2-2\cdot2018+1$,

$2019^2=(2018+1)^2=2018^2+2\cdot2018+1$,

You deduce that $2017^2-2018^2+2019^2=2018^2-2\cdot2018+1-2018^2+2018^2+2\cdot2018+1=2018^2+2$

Answer (score 1):

We know that the [difference between square numbers increases by $2$ each time](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1271618/where-does-the-constant-increase-by-2-of-differences-between-integer-square-valu) eg. because the sum of the first $n$ odd numbers is $n^2$.

Thus $(2019^2-2018^2)=(2018^2-2017^2)+2$ and thus $2019^2-2018^2+2017^2=2018^2+2$ as required